# Trouble using postgresql and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So at first I thought I would be able to solve this problem with existing questions and answers but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I installed the PG gem successfully with

```
gem install pg
```

now I am trying to migrate my database with rake db:migrate and get this error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or    directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I checked this and the server is NOT running and accepting connections.

running

```
 sudo su postgres
```

and entering a desired password yields

```
 su: unknown login: postgres
```

and running

```
 su - postgres
```

yields

```
 su: Sorry
```

I am using OS X Yosemite.  Not sure what else to do as postgres appears to be installed I just can't connect properly.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: How exactly did you install PostgreSQL? Via Homebrew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OS X run your `postgres` server using

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

And if you want to view and manipulate any of your databases type in the following in your console.

```
psql db_name
```

for example

```
psql rails_development
```